# NSTextField nextKeyView is ignored

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstextfield

- although i set the nextKeyView of the NSTextField, the focus is gained by a different NSTextField
- tried "Auto Recalculates View Loop" checked / unchecked
- toggled "Full Keyboard Access"
- tried also catching the tab in

code

```
- (BOOL)control:(NSControl*)control textView:(NSTextView*)textView doCommandBySelector:(SEL)commandSelector {

        BOOL result = NO;

        if (commandSelector == @selector(insertTab:)) {

            // tab action:
            result = NO;

        }

        return result;
    }
```

There returning YES / No, tired to set the next responder as

```
[self.window makeFirstResponder:self.nextKeyView]
```

With no success

Comment: Is `self.nextKeyView` correct when the tab-key is hit? Does backward tab (shift-tab) work?

Comment: yup, it was correct for sure

Answer (score 0):

selecting the `NSTextField` with `selectText:`, while catching the 'Tab' worked (note you have to return YES, meaning you are are processing the Tab)... you cannot rely purely on the `nextKeyView`

Put this in your `NSTextField` subclass and link the `nextKeyView`

```
- (BOOL)control:(NSControl*)control textView:(NSTextView*)textView doCommandBySelector:(SEL)commandSelector
{
    BOOL result = NO;

    if (commandSelector == @selector(insertTab:)) {

        // tab action:
        // always insert a tab character and don’t cause the receiver to end editing
        if ([self.nextKeyView isKindOfClass:[NSTextField class]]) {

            [(NSTextField *)self.nextKeyView selectText:self];
            result = YES;

        } else {

            //[textView insertTabIgnoringFieldEditor:self];
            result = NO;

        }

    }

    return result;
}
```